# Add an ID to datepicker of angular ui bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

here is my code after each dateHolder div a date picker is generated.. but want an ID on them

```
<div class="col-xs-12 tn-dateContainers" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">    
                            <div class="dateHolder mgl" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-click="openSD($event)" ng-model="dateHolder.startDate" is-open="openedSD" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-on-date-selection="false" close-text="Close" >
                                <span class="dateIcoImg"><img src="img/icon-calendar.png" alt=""></span>
                                <span class="dateIcoText">Start Date</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="dateHolder" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-click="openED($event)" ng-model="dateHolder.endDate" is-open="openedED" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-on-date-selection="false" close-text="Close">
                                <span class="dateIcoImg"><img src="img/icon-calendar.png" alt=""></span>
                                <span class="dateIcoText">End Date</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is the angular code for the same...
and also wanted add styling on the generated datepickers coz there position are at very right.

Please help me coz stuck in a project.

Thanks in Advance

```
vendorOffer.controller("DatepickerDemoCtrl" , function ($scope) {

  $scope.dateHolder = {};
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dateHolder.startDate = new Date();
    $scope.dateHolder.endDate = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.openSD = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.openedSD = true;
  };

  $scope.openED = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.openedED = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };


  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the template for the datepicker popup in the template cache with your own definition, and add styling and an id there. Beware it will affect every place in your application that you use the datepicker popup though.

```
angular.module("template/datepicker/popup.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/datepicker/popup.html",
      "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu my-css-style\" ng-style=\"{display: (isOpen && 'block') || 'none', top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}\">\n" +
      " <li ng-transclude></li>\n" +
      " <li ng-show=\"showButtonBar\" style=\"padding:10px 9px 2px\">\n" +
      "     <span class=\"btn-group\" style=\"margin-bottom:10px\">\n" +
      "         <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"today()\">{{currentText}}</button>\n" +
      "         <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-default\" ng-click=\"showWeeks = ! showWeeks\" ng-class=\"{active: showWeeks}\">{{toggleWeeksText}}</button>\n" +
      "         <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger\" ng-click=\"clear()\">{{clearText}}</button>\n" +
      "     </span>\n" +
      "     <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right\" ng-click=\"isOpen = false\">{{closeText}}</button>\n" +
      " </li>\n" +
      "</ul>\n" +
      "");
}]);
```

Comment: That is way i want, i don't want to do any change in default angular.. but Thanks